# How to give shape to view in adnroid

Tags: view, resources, shapes, drawable

How to give below shape to view in android

[image]

I tried with shape but it not proper solution.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_tab_indicator" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```